# Tile satellite images with GDAL_retile in python?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, tile

I'm trying to tile a folder of 3 band images into 256 x 256 pixel squares, (keeping the original CRS), feed this into a Unet model and then re-organize my tiled data back into one complete image to view the results of my model.

I've used [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285499/how-to-split-multiband-image-into-image-tiles-using-rasterio/290059#290059?newreg=b6dedaaa20604654b02dd639d2976e7c) but the last row of tiles are composed of the remaining pixels (edge cases).
Is there a way of either allowing for padding to be added or an automatically determined overlap to prevent this and ensure all tiles are 256x256?

`makeLastPartFull = True` is supposed to do this with cv2, so I am looking for something similar with GDAL?

I'm using Pycharm version 2021.1.

Comment: If you want to use gdal_retile, did u try its `-ps` parameter ? Looks like it should have the expected behavior